# Tratamento de erros com biblioteca de upload de imagens com PHP

Tags: php, gd

Pesquisei uma biblioteca de upload de imagens em PHP para usar em minha aplicação, optei por esta aqui. https://dhavalkapil.com/image-uploader/

Implementei e está funcionando e o sucesso de envio de uma imagem resulta em boolean(true), o mesmo que "Imagem enviada com sucesso" em termos humanos. Caso haja algum erro o que é retornado é um "Exception Object" com todas as informações relacionadas à imagem, path, argumentos e os exceptions.

O que não sei é utilizar este retorno da biblioteca para tratar o erro de modo user-friendly. Sei extrair chaves, valores de array, e para ficar amigável, imprimi o retorno do erro dentro de `<pre>`.

O código de upload é o seguinte:

```
<?php
require ("../src/ImageUploader.php");

try
{
  $imageUploader = new ImageUploader( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/upload", "meu_salt_randomico");

  $res = $imageUploader->upload($_FILES["my_image"], "meu_id");

  var_dump($res);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  var_dump($e);
}
?>
```

E o erro que preciso tratar é o seguinte:

```
Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Size limit exceeded
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\ImageUploader.php
    [line:protected] => 202
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\ImageUploader.php
                    [line] => 239
                    [function] => checkFileSize
                    [class] => ImageUploader
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => wallpapersden.com_k-nioh-2_3936x2215.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tmp\php9DDD.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 1824428
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\ImageUploader.php
                    [line] => 316
                    [function] => securityChecks
                    [class] => ImageUploader
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => wallpapersden.com_k-nioh-2_3936x2215.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\php9DDD.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 1824428
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\user-profile-photo-upload.php
                    [line] => 30
                    [function] => upload
                    [class] => ImageUploader
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => wallpapersden.com_k-nioh-2_3936x2215.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => D:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\php9DDD.tmp
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 1824428
                                )

                            [1] => meu_id123123123123
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Tentei extrair do erro os valores recebidos como se extivesse extraindo valores de um array, mas dá erro, e não sei como prosseguir com isso. Alguma referência para estudo ou orientação por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acessar aos detalhes da exceção utilize os métodos expostos:

```php
public __construct ([ string $message = "" [, int $code = 0 [, Throwable $previous = NULL ]]] )
final public getMessage ( void ) : string
final public getPrevious ( void ) : Throwable
final public getCode ( void ) : mixed
final public getFile ( void ) : string
final public getLine ( void ) : int
final public getTrace ( void ) : array
final public getTraceAsString ( void ) : string
public __toString ( void ) : string
final private __clone ( void ) : void
```

Note que estes são os únicos métodos expostos e que nenhuma propriedade está exposta na classe.

Imagino que vc esteja interessado nos métodos `getMessage` e `getCode` para fazer algo como

```php
try {
    ...
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getCode();
}
```

Comment: Retornou a mensagem de erro e pude tratar a informação, obrigado!